# Load html elements from separate urls in menu list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a site with navigation like:

```
<ul>
  <li>
   <a href="/link1">Link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="/link2">Link 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="/link3">Link 3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="/link4">Link 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When a user clicks on any of the links, the main content from each of the urls will be loaded onto one page, and the page scrolls down to the relevant section. I've tried something like below but it doesn't seem like the best solution. Is there a better way of doing this? Thanks. Should also point out that the code below doesn't work correctly, it loads the content more than once and in a random order.

```
$( "ul > li > a" ).each(function(index) {
  var newhref = $(this).attr('href');

  $.get(newhref).done(function (html) {
      $(".main-copy").append($(html).find(".main-copy"));
  });

});
```

Comment: You want to dump the content from all pages at once or replace it on every click?

Comment: I want to dump all of the content in order. So the page would be `<section id="1">HTML from Link1</section><section id="2">HTML from Link2</section><section id="3">HTML from Link3</section><section id="4">HTML from Link4</section>`

Comment: If your code works, I say it's fine as it is.

Comment: No it doesn't work, it loads the content more than once sometimes, in the order changes randomly.

Comment: I suspect it's not changing "randomly," but rather it is loading each as it gets clicked, even if that means repeatedly and in an unintended order.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with I would suggest that each link should be inside it's own -li- like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
   <a href="/link1">Link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="/link2">Link 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="/link3">Link 3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/link4">Link 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As for the JQuery, something like this should do the trick:

```
$( "ul > li > a" ).click(function(){
    $(".main-copy").load($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

I hope that sets you on the right path

Comment: Yes sorry the html should of been like that, I will edit it

Answer (score 0):

If the load thing is working, are you simply looking at the scrolling thing? Try something like this:

```js
// Creating a dummy namespace, as I don't have content to actually load via ajax.
var myNameSpace = {
  "link1": "    <p>Proin eget tortor risus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget tortor risus. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus.</p><p>Proin eget tortor risus. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Proin eget tortor risus. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit.</p><p>Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Proin eget tortor risus. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit.</p>",
  "link2": "    <p>Proin eget tortor risus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget tortor risus. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus.</p><p>Proin eget tortor risus. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Proin eget tortor risus. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit.</p><p>Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Proin eget tortor risus. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit.</p>",
  "link3": "    <p>Proin eget tortor risus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget tortor risus. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus.</p><p>Proin eget tortor risus. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Proin eget tortor risus. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit.</p><p>Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Proin eget tortor risus. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit.</p>",
  "link4": "    <p>Proin eget tortor risus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget tortor risus. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus.</p><p>Proin eget tortor risus. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Proin eget tortor risus. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit.</p><p>Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Proin eget tortor risus. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit.</p>"
};


  // Take each of the navigation elements, and use them to create the content sections
  $("nav a").each(function() {
    /***
     * This would be where you'd first want to load
     *  your HTML content, rather than using the namespace.
     ***/
    // Get the actual text of the anchor, we'll use that later
    var target = $(this).attr("href").substring(1);

    // create the section tag...
    var myTargetEl = document.createElement("section");

    // set the id for the link to use as a target
    $(myTargetEl).attr("id", target).append("<h2>" + target + "</h2>").append(myNameSpace[target]);

    // Add the section we've created to the content pane
    $(".content-pane").append(myTargetEl);

    // AND CHANGE THE ACTUAL LINK -- I don't want to reload
    //  this content every time!
    $(this).attr("href", "#" + target);
  });

  $("nav a").click(function() {
    var target = $($(this).attr("href"));
    if (target.length) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
      }, 1000);
    }
  })
```

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.content-pane {
  position: relative;
  left: 120px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <a href="/link1">Content 1</a>
  <a href="/link2">Content 2</a>
  <a href="/link3">Content 3</a>
  <a href="/link4">Content 4</a>
</nav>
<div class="content-pane">
</div>
```

As far as the load thing goes, simply load each link into its own section tag. In fact, use the link list to create the section blocks, so that if you add more navigation elements, they'll load dynamically.

Modified the code so that there are no sections being inserted manually, they're created by the link tags themselves. As to how you'd load them, you seem to be doing that all right -- all you're missing is the changing the link's HREF to point to the appropriate section each time.

Comment: sorry should of said it doesn't work correctly, edited my question to explain

Comment: Thank you. I've tried that with append the html element I want to add to the page but it duplicates the content and doesn't put it in the right order.

Comment: The big trick to this is remember to change the href of your anchors! If you don't, it'll just keep reloading that content. Make the loading happen when the document itself loads, then immediately turn the links to internal references and either show/hide or scroll on click, your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Are these links hard-coded or dynamically generated?
In either case, get all these links into a JavaScript Array:`var links=['link1','link2'...]`

Since you want to dump all the content by navigating through each of these links, you can loop-through links and append content

```
for(i=0;i<links.length;i++) {
  var link = links[i];
  $.ajax(link).done(function(htmlContent){
                    //set contents to some section or div 
                    });
}
```

Now the links themselves can be a #href tags with-in the page.

My suggestion would be not to navigate using Jquery on UL -> LI path to get the list of links.